# HTTP/1.1 400 Illegal character 0x20 for the Bulk API request

Tags: rest-api

I am doing Trailhead from the link: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/api_basics/units/api_basics_bulk and using the Workbench REST executor to bulkyfy the code. I am getting below error:

```
Raw Response
HTTP/1.1 400 Illegal character 0x20
Content-Length: 0
X-Cnection: close
```

I have make sure I am using valid SessionId using SOAP API tool.

Not sure what is the issue?

[image]

Making sure using correct sessionId:

[image]

Comment: Try removing the space between `X-SFDC-Session` and the `:` which follows.

Comment: This question certainly has nothing to do with Apex.

Comment: This question is about what happens when you violate the rules of HTTP, which any server in the world is bound to give you an error message for. The fact that you happen to be using salesforce.com doesn't mean this question is salesforce.com-related.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for the issue, I should not be using any space between X-SFDC-Session as mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_basics_about_uri.htm) and it should be like

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Accept: application/json
X-SFDC-Session: 00D7F0000001I8v!ARgAQDJzlAoZrnEglefn9IN_8EsrRA.3E6lWmDC1Bm5r9FuUYu0yVYVh.KCe9yRFx63.zftlZIliCNxqrs1spJlJTheYy7YM
```

Comment: The documentation tells you how to access the API, [right here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_basics_about_uri.htm).